# Can current transformers be cascaded?

Tags: ground, current-transformer

I have a GFI circuit that's part of an EVSE (electric car charger) that is known to work.

What I need to do is be able to support testing for residual current on two pairs of conductors simultaneously.

I could run all four conductors through the coil, but they don't fit (for the purpose of this question, please do not simply suggest using a larger coil. That's not the point).

I could duplicate the circuit completely and use two coils, but that seems wasteful.

What I'd like to propose for discussion is wiring two GFI coils either in series or parallel, with the idea that a residual current in either coil would be fed into the amplifier and the rest of the GFI coil (see [this application note](http://www.crmagnetics.com/Products/Assets/ProductPDFs/Precision%20Rectifier%20Circuit%20for%20CT%20Signal%20Conditioning.pdf) for the schematic of the GFI in question).

Comment: I'm confused. You mention two pairs of conductors, then you talk about all four conductors not fitting through the core that you have. These are not equivalent situations. Which do you want?

Comment: You have 3 overlapping sets of advice. I do not have vast in-field CT experience BUT am currently developing a multi input energy metering related application using CTs, series sense resistors and Hall sensors in various places (and Rogowski coils may follow :-) ). So I have had more recent CT experience than I really wanted :-) :-(. So ...

Comment: ...  || I'd say that two in series with phasing correct **AND** a burden resistor across each one SHOULD be OK. The "better" EE solution is both in phase with own burden resistor and each with one side grounded and each feeding their own R2 (R2A & R2B) into the the same opamp inverting terminal. As this is a summing node and always at ground the currents will sum OK. Note that these should all be on the same phase or the summing will be uncertain under any arrangement. || Is it single phase?

Comment: Note that in the cct you show the LM324 input offset voltage may oppose CT current and it may take some noticeable input to oppose it. You want to look carefully at the voltages produced and resultant current at IC and see how what this does it compares to the WORST CASE input offset voltage (of about 3 mV from memory). This may be acceptable depending on how sensitive you want the trip setting to be.

Comment: Although the schematic in the ap note has no values in it, the GFI circuit I have is known to work with one coil. The question is whether it is possible (or advisable) to easily adapt it to work with two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can connect the current transformer outputs in parallel, which will look something like the below. This is called a "summation CT" arrangement. The "A" ammeter represents your sensing circuit.

[image]

Industrially, we use a similar arrangement to implement frame earth fault protection on HV switchboards. Make sure you get the polarity of the connections right. If you get one of the connections the wrong way around, you will make a "subtraction CT" arrangement which has zero output if the two circuits have equal fault current - not what you want!

As for all CT circuits - ensure you never open-circuit the CT outputs, and ensure that your sensing circuit can withstand the maximum prospective fault current for the required time.

---

PS: Don't connect CT's in series. You end up with contradictions like the below.

Contradictions in CT circuits are usually resolved with a 'bang'.

[image]

Comment: Please see my comment on the original question. I am **NOT** saying you are wrong - just that a different approach can be taken if desired as long as it is designed.

Comment: The summation CT - parallel - makes sense, and it has the particular attraction of working with the existing circuit unmodified. I will give it a try on the bench.

Comment: Sure enough, it works!

Answer (score 1):

I think that wiring them in series should work, presuming the coils are identical. Opposite currents through the coils well induce opposing voltages. However, you need to make sure that you have an identical burden resistor across each coil.

I have not tried this myself, so I cannot vouch for how effective it is. There is a very simple way to test it, though. Place the same wires through both coils so that they go forwards through one and backwards through the other. The idea is to cancel out the voltage induced on one coil with the other coil. Then feed a signal through. If you get zero, then it works. Try adding another wire through one of the coils and see if the current in that wire is sensed accurately, even with current in the other wires.

Comment: I'm not sure that wiring CT secondaries in series is a great idea. (See my answer.) Did you mean 'parallel'? Perhaps a sketch would clarify.

Comment: Well, if you're going to connect them to an ammeter, then they need to be in parallel.  I was thinking in terms of the current passing through inducing a voltage across the coil, and you need to put voltages in series.

Comment: Please see my comment on the original question. I am **NOT** saying you are wrong - just that a different approach can be taken if desired as long as it is designed.

Comment: @alex.forencich I was astounded just now to come across a website post that quoted a now deleted stack exchange post from March 1st. I like your droll** "likely slander" and "could be considered harassment" :-). A search on terms in the post show that someone has taken a "news" article, added my name and some (partially incorrect, fortunately) details and posted them to SE. Looks like someone was seeking to make life hard for me. Alas, one of the sites which ripoff SE posts has placed the heading in a sidebar and now it proclaims its message in 657 Google hits. It's obvious if you trace ....

Comment: ..through it that the action is malicious - ie NOBODY posts that sort of stuff with real names on genuine sites and it appears with "a man" on numerous sites  - but whether I will be able to convince the people concerned to delete the post is TBD. - Russell
|| ** - well, I hope it was droll :-). || Looks like somebody is out to get me. Now, who did I annoy just prior to March 1st? ... :-) :-) :-) :-) || NB: I had not seen the post until just now. I'd have hoped that somebody would have notified me. Deleting my (or anyone else's) name out of such a post instantly MIGHT save it from the copiers.